# Isomorphism of tensor products of simple artinian algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, tensor-products

I have a very specific question about isomorphisms that arose while reading about simple artinian algebras and Brauer equivalence. The setting is

> Let $A$ be a simple central artinian algebra over the field $K$, $B\subset A$ a finite-dimensional simple subalgebra, and $C$ its centraliser.

We know from previous steps in the proof that

> - The $K$-algebras $C$ and $B^\circ\otimes_K A$ are similar/Brauer equivalent, i.e. there exist $m,n$ such that $$C\otimes_KM_m(K)\cong(B^\circ\otimes_KA)\otimes_KM_n(K)$$
> - The $K$-algebra $C$ is simple artinian with $Z(C)=Z(B)=:L$ (a field, because the subalgebras are simple).

The text claims that $B\otimes_L C$ and $A\otimes_KL$ are similar $L$-algebras and it justifies this without further qualification by means of
$$(B\otimes_LC)\otimes_KM_m(K)\cong((B\otimes_LB^\circ)\otimes_KA)\otimes_KM_n(K)$$
and then using that $B\otimes_LB^\circ\cong M_d(L)$ for some $d$ (since $B$ is an $L$-CSA). According to my understanding, this isomorphism should run in detail something like
$$(B\otimes_LC)\otimes_K M_m(K)\cong B\otimes_L(C\otimes_K M_m(K))\color{red}{\cong}B\otimes_L((B^\circ\otimes_K A)\otimes_K M_n(K))\cong((B\otimes_LB^\circ)\otimes_KA)\otimes_KM_n(K)\cong(M_d(L)\otimes_KA)\otimes_KM_n(K)\cong(A\otimes_KL)\otimes_KM_{nd}(K),$$
where the isomorphisms are supposed to be that of $L$-algebras.

Now try as I might, I just can't understand why the highlighted isomorphism should hold, i.e. why
$$B\otimes_L(C\otimes_K M_m(K))\cong B\otimes_L((B^\circ\otimes_K A)\otimes_K M_n(K))$$
as $L$-algebras. All we know is that the right components of the products are isomorphic as $K$-algebras, why should that get upgraded to an $L$-algebra isomorphism?